# Are hop leaves edible?

Tags: vegetables

I had to thin my hop plants and I have some hop leaves. I know people use hop shoots and hops for cooking but I was wondering if hop leaves are edible and, if so, how they are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do some research<sup>1</sup>, but: yes, hop leaves are edible, e.g. as salad.

You might be better off with tender *young* leaves, but there are no critical ingredients that should deter you from giving them a try. Commonly one would expect the leaves to be used in a salad, but for older leaves I'd be tempted to add a heating step, like adding a handful in a stir-fry or omelette - think spinach or chard, for example.

As for the chemical compounds that influence the medicinal properties <sup>2</sup>, the contents are extremely low in the leaves, so unlike for shots or flowers there is no limit to the amount you can safely consume.

---

<sup>1</sup> Sources (in German, Endlish souces were less fruitful):

http://www.vivalranger.com/index.php/wissensdatenbank/essbare-pflanzen/126-hopfen-wilder-humulus-lupulus
http://selbstbewusstgesund.de/ernaehrung/essbare-wildkraeuter-3/

<sup>2</sup> We explicitly do not discuss health and nutrition here, but some foods should be consumed in limited amounts nevertheless. For hops, that is mainly due to ingredients with calming and estrogen-like properties.